# What to modify in my query to fix literal format string error?

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime-format

Literal does not match format string

```
select TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(A.DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY') || TO_CHAR(A.TIME),'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
from dual , TAB A
```

how to modify my query so not produce the above error ?

A.TIME type is varchar2(20) and A.DATE is date

I also have this condition

```
Select TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(A.DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY') || TO_CHAR(A.TIME),'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')  < TO_DATE('20/04/2015','DD/MM/YYYY') +1
from dual , TAB A
```

Its producing error how to modify it

Comment: Please provide data in those columns. Without them we can't tell you why format doesn't match.

Comment: Please provide some samples of data. If your column A.TIME contains only time then change the mask to TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(A.DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY') || TO_CHAR(A.TIME,'HH24:MI:SS'),'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'). Also if you sum A.DATE + A.TIME you should have the desired resulting date without conversions from char to date and vice a verse. Date data type is represented as floating point number in Oracle. The the part before the decimal point represent days and the part after decimal point represent time.

Comment: @AlexPoole the query is long I have concetrate on the date condition

Comment: @JanisBaiza Stefan Yodanov.. structure of those columns would be good ?

Comment: @Moudiz what do you mean by structure if those columns would be good? Whant is the type of these columns?

Comment: @Moudiz Please add the data type details of the columns. And show some sample data.

Comment: @StefanYordanov I guess the error is in this TO_CHAR(A.TIME),'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS' .. I guess I should add a date format next to A.TIME. Ill include there type

Comment: @Moudiz How about posting a test case? Some sample data? And the data type details?

Comment: @LalitKumarB I include the data type , I cant provide sample data because its for the company

Comment: @Moudiz - you can show a sample date and time, they are hardly secrets on their own. We need to see what format you are storing the time in particular. Is it actually HH24:MI:SS, or do you have more than that - fractional seconds, other text, ...? Something in that column does not match the format you're using. (It may be a record you think isn't relevant, depending on how the optimiser is choosing to get the data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(A.DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY') || ' ' || A.TIME,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
from dual , TAB A
```

This will work only if data in your A.TIME column is in format HH24:MI:SS.
You should use case-when to deal with boolean expressions in select list.

```
     Select 
    case when TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(A.DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY') ||
         A.TIME,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')  
            < (TO_DATE('20/04/2015','DD/MM/YYYY') +1) 
    then 'Y' else 'N' end
   from dual , TAB A
```

Answer (score 2):

> A.TIME type is varchar2(20) and A.DATE is date

*You should never ever store date and time elements separately.* A **DATE** data type has both date and time elements to the seconds precision.

```
SQL> SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL;

SYSDATE
-------------------
14/05/2015 12:57:42
```

Fix you design first.

As a possible workaround, you could append the date literal to the time, and then apply **TO_DATE** to convert it into date.

For example,

```
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS';

Session altered.

SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT SYSDATE dt, '13:05:10' tm FROM dual
  3  )
  4  SELECT TO_DATE(
  5     TO_CHAR(dt,'DD/MM/YYYY')
  6     || ' '||
  7     tm,
  8     'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as "datetime"
  9  FROM data;

datetime
-------------------
14/05/2015 13:05:10
```

Your modified query would look like:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(
   TO_CHAR(t.date,'DD/MM/YYYY')
   || ' '||
   t.time,
   'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') AS "datetime"
FROM your_table t;
```

The problem you might face is that if the TIME column doesn't adhere to the format `'HH24:MI:SS` then you won't be able to make it work. It is completely dependent on the format because you have stored it as string.

Comment: I have this condition 2 < TO_DATE('20/04/2015','DD/MM/YYYY') +1